# How to improve several shortest paths search over the same graph ?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, nodes, graph-theory

I had the next situation and i need to find the best optimization to solve the problem.

I graph **G**

for putting an example lets asume the graph looks like this
[image]

And the problem require find the addition of the weights in shortest paths (just lets call it `SP`) between several vertices and add them all.

I mean if the shortest paths between `a - b` is `a -> c -> d` his `SP` would be `x0 + x1 + x2`

So a set of my problem would look like this:

- a - g
- a - h
- e - f
- .... etc

So the naive solution is to found the `SP` for between every set every time

```
SP(a,g) + SP(a,h) + SP(e,f) + ... = result
```

So this is when the optimization task begin , i already implement two improvements but i need the best optimization (if it is possible), let see what i already did:

1. Save every result of every shortest path found so if there is asked again i had the problem

example. if the `SP` between `a - g` is `w`  i save it so if i asked again which is the value of `SP` between `a - g` or `g - a` i already know the result

2. Save every subsequent `SP` found and save it

example.

If i asked to found the SP between `a - g`. Lets assume that the shortest paths between that two vertices is `a -> c -> d -> j -> g` so the `SP` would be

```
x0 + x1 + x2 + x3
```

so i can save  `a - g` but also i can save the SP of all the subsequent paths found.

for example the shortest paths between `a` and `j` is `a -> c -> d -> j` 
or the paths between `c and j` is `c -> d -> j`

here are all the `SP` founds

```
SP(a,c) = x0
SP(a,d) = x0 + x1
SP(a,j) = x0 + + x1 + x2

SP(c,d) = x1
SP(c,j) = x1 + x2
SP(c,g) = x1 + x2 + x3

SP(d,j) = x2
SP(d,g) = x2 + x3

SP(j,g) = x3
```

And i save every result.

So now this last improvement has save a lot time but it seems don't enough since the quantity of nodes and the set of the SP to found is considerable big.

So any suggestion or any particular algorithms that i can use to improve this problems (i hope been enough clear please write a comment if any details is not explained) ?

Comment: Do you know anything about which pairs you're going to be summing over? Is there some predictable pattern, or is it totally arbitrary?

Comment: You can use a triangular relationship: if b is on shortest path from a to c then `SP(a,c) = SP(a,b) + SP(b,c)`

Comment: @templatetypedef there is not particular patterns

Comment: @ZoffDino interesting suggest, but can you develop a more your answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have many pairs to compute, consider [Floyd-Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm); it will give you the shortest-path distance from any point to any other point (at the cost of O(n^3) runtime).

Comment: Ill take it on count , but do you you think is a good idea ? since maybe i can process paths that will not be asked in the set so there is going to be a  waste of time

Comment: If the number of pairs you end up processing is comparable to (or greater than) the number of vertices in the graph, you have a good chance of saving time overall.

Comment: Certainly that algorithm help a lot , from 4 min running pass to less than a minute, but i pretty sure that must be something else to improve the problem resolution time

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dijustra to search for the shortest path between one node and all other nodes, and cache all the length of the shortest paths using a Hash table.

Then, for a given set of pairs of nodes, you can quickly extract the path length from the Hash table.

Comment: i am sorry i don't follow your answer (i'm a bit rust in algorithms) can you exemplify your solution ?

Comment: @eli.rodriguez I think Jerry's answer is better

Comment: Well i think the approach is very similar ,  compute all the graph and cache the results

Comment: @eli.rodriguez   yes, it's similar, but Jerry's method is more straightforward. The method I stated would be faster when there are fewer edges, but for your case it is unneeded.